# How to count values since the first non nan value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df`:

```
         CODE    TMAX
0        000130  NaN
1        000130  NaN
2        000130  32.0
3        000130  32.2
4        000130  31.1
5        158328  22.5
6        158328  8.8
7        158328  NaN
8        158328  NaN
9        158328  9.2
...      ...     ...
```

I want to count the number of non nan values and the number of nan values in the 'TMAX' column. But i want to count since the first non NaN value.

Expected result: 6 non nan values and 2 NaN values.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not change the question once answered. If you have another question that is different from the one you are asking, please ask another question or do some research on your own. It will make people visiting your question confused as the question and answer differ. @Javier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `first_valid_index` to find the first non-NaN index and filter. Then use `isna` to create a boolean mask and count the values.

```
output = (
    df.loc[df.TMAX.first_valid_index():, 'TMAX']
    .isna()
    .value_counts()
    .rename({True: 'NaN', False: 'notNaN'})
)
```

Output

```
notNaN    6
NaN       2
Name: TMAX, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) for filter out first `NaN`s and then count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `rename` index values by `dict`:

```
m = df.TMAX.notna()
s = m[m.cummax()].value_counts().rename({True:'non NaNs',False:'NaNs'})
print (s)
non NaNs    6
NaNs        2
Name: TMAX, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = (df.TMAX
            .truncate(before=df.TMAX.first_valid_index())
            .mask(pd.Series.notna, other="non-NaN")
            .value_counts(dropna=False))
```

where we [`truncate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.truncate.html) the series before its [`first valid index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) i.e., first non-Nan index, and then turn it into a `NaN` or not `NaN` series with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html). Then we [count the values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) (including `NaN`s),

to get

```
>>> result

non-NaN    6
NaN        2
```