# How can I count the number of NaNs in a column until the first non-NaN value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Lorem | NaN |
| Ipsum | NaN |
| Dolor | NaN |
| Sit | 25 |
| Amet | 34 |
| Etc | NaN |
| Something else | NaN |

I would like to count the number of `NaN`s in `Column B` until the first non-NaN number (which is 25 here). So, the expected returned value is 3.

I think there is something involving `notna()` and `first_valid_index`, but I cannot seem to put the information together. This problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029884/how-to-count-values-since-the-first-non-nan-value) but I want before, not since the first NaN.

Can you help me?

Comment: As you mentioned, `df["Column B"].first_valid_index()` :ğ

Comment: I've upvoted the @MustafaAydın's comment. it is the valid answer. Just one remark: if all the values are valid , the function will return `None`

Comment: I really can't see how this question is a duplicate of the mentioned question!